# Android PermissionsDispatch library returning null on location and not generating permisions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-location

I got tired of playing around with the new permission system in Android and as such started to look for other options. The permissionsDispatch library seems amazing but I can't get it to work. I have been trying for the past two hours to get the code to work to no avail. It is a fairly small and simple example:

```
@RuntimePermissions
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final int MY_REQUEST_PERMISSION_COARSE_LOCATION = 45;
    public static final String TAG = "MAINACTIVITYITS";
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GoogleApiBuilder();

    }

    public void GoogleApiBuilder() {
        // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    @NeedsPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    public void mLocationSetter(){
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationSetter();
        Log.i(TAG, mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "");
        Toast.makeText(this, mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @OnShowRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    public void locationRationale(PermissionRequest request){
        showRationaleDialog(R.string.permission_coarse_rationale, request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // NOTE: delegate the permission handling to generated method
        MainActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);
    }

    private void showRationaleDialog(@StringRes int messageResId, final PermissionRequest request){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_allow, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        request.proceed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.button_deny, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        request.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage(messageResId)
                .show();

    }
}
```

My issue here comes from the mLastLocation instance variable returning null even after being annotated with the @NeedsPermission tag and the rationale is not showing at all. Basically, what I am trying to do is go by the same tutorial for getting the last known location inside Google https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html but using this library instead of having to write all the code for permissions. Am I missing something? All I want is the last known location.

Comment: did you add this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` in manifest?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Indeed, I also enabled the annotation processors and everything. The last remaining part is to see what is going wrong with the code. I submitted an issue inside the main github repo for the library(it was changed as a question and closed with no result) and it still isn't working

Comment: is there any exception ? did the permission dialog shown?

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 the permission dialog did not show and the exception comes from mLastLocation being null and this the Log.i portion which shows the .getLatitude() not showing since mLastLocation returns null.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [this](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission) library for getting user access location permission

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I still want to get this one to work and know why it is not working though.